# Is there a way to have text display on the UIActionSheet buttons the way it does from the contacts app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, ios

When you select text message from a contact in the contact's app you get a list of phone numbers and email addresses with the 'type' also in the button, however the 'type' is styled differently. Is there a way to get this effect with UIActionSheet buttons or would I have to roll my own?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no officially supported way to do this. You might be able to dig through the view hierarchy and add subviews to the buttons containing text that's styled the way you want it, but it's a bad idea because:

1. It'll probably break in a future release when Apple changes how they organize the view in an action sheet.
2. Even if they don't change the views, they may change how they look, leaving your stuff looking very odd in its new context.

If you roll your own, there's still the chance your "action sheet" will look different from all of the other ones on the system, but at least it'll look exactly how you intended it to look.

Comment: Cool. I thought that might be the case. It's too bad, but that's just how it goes.